# Angularjs view not showing bound data in ng-repeat when it loads

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This seems like a simple question, but I haven't found the answer.  I have a view that has:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="org in vm.organizationList">
        <td>{{org.name}}</td>
        <td>{{org.description}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And my controller does something like:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('Organization', organization);

organization.$inject = ['logger'];

function organization(logger) {
    /* jshint validthis:true */
    var vm = this;
    vm.organizationList = [];

    activate();

    function activate() {
        vm.organizationList = getList();
    }
}
```

I've removed the details of how it gets the data to be more concise.  The problem is that when the form loads, I don't see the data in the table.  It is only when I leave that view and go to another view that I see the data for a second.

How can I fix?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using `$http` to load the data, trigger `$scope.$apply()` after populating your data.

```
organization.$inject = ['logger', '$scope'];

function organization(logger, $scope) {
    /* jshint validthis:true */
    var vm = this;
    vm.organizationList = [];

    activate();

    function activate() {
        vm.organizationList = getList();
        $scope.$apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: You called it, I'm not ussing $http (I'm using the google cloud endpoints client).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check that:

1) You have set `ng-app` directive.

2) `vm.organizationList` is not empty.